# Какую джумлу выбрать - 2.5 или 3.2?

Tags: joomla, cms

Есть желание научиться сайтостроению, хочу попробовать на джумле. Для начала хочу сделать небольшой информационный сайт. Опыта особого нет, так, верхушки, но есть понимание. С какой версии лучше начать - 2.5 или 3.2 - и почему?

Comment: Лучше не Выбирать джумлу

Comment: @lyadnSV, в мире ПО, как правило, более свежая **стабильная** версия всегда лучше, особенно если не нужно устраивать миграцию с предыдущей версии. Более интересный функционал, больше обплытых подводных камней, все такое. На официальных сайтах всегда будут выложены либо стабильные версии, либо отдельно стабильные, а рядом - нестабильные, о чем будет красноречиво сказано.

Comment: Да, лучше для обучения Джумлу не выбирать.

Answer (score 2):

Выбирайте последнюю стабильную версию. Сейчас это версия 3.3. Почему? Как правило, это безопасность. Каждая новая версия закрывает имеющиеся уязвимости + добавляет новый функционал.

Поддержка версии 2.5 будет осуществляться только до декабря 2014 года. Поэтому выбор в вашем случае очевиден.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь версией 3.2, она функциональна, и больше возможностей.